Only time-sensitive notifications delivered on iPhone
I have an iPhone 12 with iOS 17.5.1 on it.  Since some time ago (can't pinpoint exactly when), I only get time-sensitive notifications, e.g. calendar reminders or push notifications from authenticator app.  I don't get any notifications from any other apps.  My main concern is that I don't get notifications for new emails, messages, etc.
I checked all the usual suspects, including background data, notification permissions on specific apps, etc.
Considering that the issue affects ALL apps on the phone, this has to be something more global.
Need to add: the phone is corporate-managed using Intune.  I had our admins check all the settings - everything is correct.  Also, I seem to be the only one in our company having this issue. I tried deleting Intunes and the relevant management profile, the reinstalling them - to no avail.  With the profile removed, I can't access email, so can't check that.
Any suggestions?

Do you have any focus in use?

@Thinkr No. I checked that (should have added in the question).  No focus and never used.
